# Mapping Subdomains to Locale Directories in Next.js v13 Doesn't Work on Production (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, next.js, subdomain, locale, middleware

I'm trying to map subdomains to locale-specific directories in a Next.js (version 13) app using TypeScript. However, I'm experiencing issues in the production environment.

Here's the mapping I'm trying to achieve:

- `www.domain.com` -> `en-US`
- `he.domain.com` -> `he-IL`
- `fr.domain.com` -> `fr-FR`

To implement this, I've set up locale-specific directories (e.g., `src/app/[locale]`) and am using middleware to map the request to the relevant directory based on the subdomain.

Here's a simplified version of my middleware code in TypeScript:

```js
import { I18NConfig } from "next/dist/server/config-shared";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

const i18n: I18NConfig = {
  locales: ["en-US", "he-IL", "fr-FR"],
  defaultLocale: "en-US",
  localeDetection: false,
  domains: [
    {
      domain: "www.domain.com",
      defaultLocale: "en-US",
    },
    {
      domain: "he.domain.com",
      defaultLocale: "he-IL",
    },
    {
      domain: "fr.domain.com",
      defaultLocale: "fr-FR",
    },
  ],
};

type Locale = (typeof i18n)["locales"][number];
const subdomains = i18n.domains!.map((domain) => domain.domain.split(".")[0]);
const subdomainLocale: Record<string, Locale> = {
  ...Object.fromEntries(
    i18n.domains!.map((domain) => [
      domain.domain.split(".")[0],
      domain.defaultLocale,
    ])
  ),
};

export const getValidSubdomain = (host?: string) => {
  let subdomain: string | null = null;

  if (!host && typeof window !== "undefined") {
    host = window.location.host;
  }
  const candidat = host?.split(".")[0];
  if (candidat && subdomains.includes(candidat)) {
    subdomain = candidat;
  }
  return subdomain;
};

function getLocale(request: NextRequest): Locale {
  const host = request.headers.get("host");
  const subdomain = getValidSubdomain(host as string);

  if (subdomain) {
    return subdomainLocale[subdomain];
  } else {
    return i18n.defaultLocale;
  }
}

const PUBLIC_FILE = /\.(.*)$/; // Files

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const url = request.nextUrl.clone();
  if (PUBLIC_FILE.test(url.pathname) || url.pathname.includes("_next")) return;
  const locale = getLocale(request);
  url.pathname = `/${locale}${url.pathname}`;
  return NextResponse.rewrite(url);
}
```

This setup works as expected in my development environment when I navigate to a path using the format **`/{locale}`**, but when I deploy to production, the locale doesn't seem to be correctly determined from the subdomain. Instead, each subdomain redirects to the root folder and doesn't consider the locale directory.

Please note that I am specifically using the App Router, not the Pages Router, for this purpose. Also, I have ensured that the production environment is correctly set up with the same locale and subdomain configuration as my development environment.

I would appreciate any advice on how to debug this issue or any suggestions for alternative approaches to achieve this subdomain-to-locale mapping in Next.js using TypeScript with the App Router.

---

Here's what I'm expecting:

- `www.domain.com` should render localized files from `/en-US` directory.
- `he.domain.com` should render localized files from `/he-IL` directory.
- `fr.domain.com` should render localized files from `/fr-FR` directory.

Essentially, each subdomain should correspond to a relevant locale, allowing the app to render localized files from the respective `/{locale}` directory, rather than the root folder.

Comment: Have you verified that the "Host" header is correctly set in your production environment? Sometimes you need to pass X-Forwarded-Host, or even other headers (for example in Netlify's case) and read them depending on how your infrastructure is set up.